# Property 'parse' does not exist on type 'new () => T'

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, typescript3.0

I'm working on a general data service in Angular witch can handle data models and communicate with backend.

Now I have multiple services to each API endpoints, same code, just the model type (and of course the URI) is the difference.

I started develop a multipurpose service on this way:

Here is BaseModel to define most basic things on models, `models/base_model/base.model.ts`:

```
export class BaseModel {
  id: number;
  prepareToSave: () => void;
  static parse () {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
  }
}
```

Here is a Photoalbum model to define a data set, `models/photoalbum/photoalbum.model.ts`:

```
export class Photoalbum {
  id: number;
  public: boolean;
  name: string;

  static parse(data: any) {
    return new this(data);
  }

  prepareToSave() {
    return {
      // convert datas to backend
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the DataService to communicate the backend, `services/data/data.service.ts`:

```
export class DataService<T extends BaseModel> {
  constructor(
    private type: new () => T,
    private url: string,
    private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Promise<T[]> {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe( (result: any) => {
        const data: T[] = [];
        result.forEach( (item: any) => {
          data.push(this.type.parse(item)); // error in this line
        });
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

Now I get this error in DataService:

```
Property 'parse' does not exist on type 'new () => T'.
```

I'm using TypeScript 3.5.2 with tslint 5.9.1 if this is relevant.

Is there any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#class-types

Comment: @netdjw did you ever get any answer for this problem? I'm facing the same issue, but found no solution :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, `parse` only exists as a static property of `BaseModel`, so it's no surprise that you are receiving an error.
Change the type of `type` in the constructor.

```
  constructor(
    private type: { new (): T, parse(data: any): any },
    private url: string,
    private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Then update the definition of the parse method to accept one argument.

```
export class BaseModel {
  id: number;
  prepareToSave: () => void;
  static parse (item: any): any {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I have a question. In this case maybe I lost the core of the concept, isn't it? I want to use not a `BaseModel` as data type. I want to give the data type in parameter to the service. Something like this: `constructor(dataService: DataService<Photoalbum>) { }`

Comment: @netdjw I see. I've updated my answer. Let me know if it's still not what you're looking for.